# Can't open text file resource in Xcode 4 c++ tool?

Tags: c++, resources, xcode4, fstream

I am working on figuring out how to use Xcode 4 to debug c++ projects.

I have basically copy pasted a working c++ executable that when compiled from the terminal ran fine.

However, i was thinking it might be nice to use Xcode for debugging. So I am trying to migrate the single .cpp file into Xcode as a command line tool.

I need to read in a file called numbers.txt (which I supply through a command line argument) which is located in my project directory, and then out put to a file (whose name I also specify as an argument.)

The problem I am running into is that the files that are supplied as command line arguments are failing to open.

```
    ifstream in;
    ofstream out;
    in.open(argv[1]);
    out.open(argv[2]);
```

I have checked to make sure that the arguments are being properly passed and are named correctly. The `ifstream in` is being supplied with `numbers.txt', which I want to open a text file that I already have.

However when I check to make sure the `ifstream` is open:

```
    if(in.is_open() == false){
          cerr << "Unable to open input file" << endl;
          return 1;
    }
```

I get the error.

I suspect this has something to do with how Xcode organizes the project.

my `numbers.txt` file is just sitting in the Xcode project folder, and I have only one `.cpp` class and one product, the executable.

anyone know what I am missing here?

Comment: Err.. is this a question about C++, or just about finding files on your disk? The code looks OK...

Comment: I am not really sure. The code worked fine when I ran it from command line with they .txt file in the same directory as the executable. I'm guessing that it has something to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executable built by Xcode is in a different folder than the project. Passing in the name of the file without an absolute path before it will cause the executable to look for it in the wrong place, which is why it can't be found. Some of the possible solutions are to include the file as part of the build process (so it ends up in the same directory as the executable) or to pass the file to be opened by its absolute path. There are other ways to solve the problem, too, but hopefully that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I added a build phase to copy the two text files I need. But I'm not sure where I should put them. It appears the likely options are:  "Executables", "Products Directory", "Resources". Do I need to specify a subpath also?

Comment: @weezybizzle: You could supply a fully qualified path name. You could also do a test output where you output to a relative location and then wherever that file appears, put your text file there.

Comment: The more I read about this the more confused I am getting. I can't seem to figure out where the executable actually ends up. Is it in some directory called build? (in build locations it says build) or is it in a bundle? I'm so lost, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @weezybizzle: It doesn't actually matter where your executable ends up. What matters is the working directory. You can find out what the working directory is by doing the test that I showed before. Something simple like `FILE *f = fopen("test.txt"); fprintf(f, "hi"); fclose(f);` Wherever test.txt appears, that's where you should put your text file.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but i have faced the same problem now, and it is easy to solve. Just copy the file in the build phase.
Here is an screenshot of the final result (note the destination, subpath and checkbox):

[image: copy item]